# A-Frame not loading assets from Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, aframe

im testing a-frame with ionic and angular. I get a-frame runs great with them, even tried on my device and looks awesome.

The problem comes when i try to load an img on the a-sky from a property of the component.

I got this working:

```
<ion-content>
    <a-scene>
      <a-sky src="assets/puydesancy.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
</ion-content>
```

But if i try this:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="sky" [src]="myImgPath">
  </a-assets>
  <a-sky src="#sky"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Don't work and get this log message:

> THREE.webglrenderer 83

Seems that a-frame cant load the image coming this way but dont know why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of A-Frame are you using? Are you sure `myImgPath` points to the right resourcelocation or the attribute in your component is typed correctly?

I've put together [a plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/AYnzi2a699A9SlujRxm0?p=preview), it correctly displays the image source on an `a-sky` in conjunction with Angular and A-Frame 0.5.0.

What might help is to use **[attr.*]** instead.

```
<a-assets>
    <img id="sky" [attr.src]="myImgPath">
</a-assets>
```

I am not formiliar with the ionic framework, but I would assume it should work just fine with `ng-template`.

Comment: tried to put it in an ionic example, the color attribute works, the src not so much, any idea why: http://plnkr.co/edit/V8zbOi?p=preview ?

Comment: I have just checked your plunkr. Everything seems to be is correctly set, however when the `a-scene` is created inside the `ionic-nav` component it does not render. I've even moved it outside of the `ionic-content` component and the assets in the scene are not rendered. It seems that just the Ionic framework does not work with A-Frame that well. [editted plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/23ohXpzuXybk0EPlLoon?p=preview)

Comment: @ShanevandenBogaard thx, I was sure i was missing something, You can use it with the ion-content, but the dynamic attributes [attr] won't work properly i guess

Comment: Thanks this works! but anyway i had to add `crossorigin="anonymous"` to make it works too.

Answer (score 0):

You've got cross-reference `src="#sky"` so when `myImgPath` is finally available and change detection is triggered, `a-sky` component still doesn't know about this, and it already had run `loadAsset` internal hook.
Shortly speaking asset management system doesn't work well in Angular, but there is the other way which is not officially recommended:

```
<a-scene>
  <!-- a-assets removed! -->
  <a-sky [attr.src]="myImgPath"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

See: https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/primitives/a-gltf-model.html