# How to load a-frame asset from Angular property binding

Tags: angular, aframe

I'm trying to load an OBJ file from my back end and display it with A-Frame. I can get it to load the model right if I hard code the url in the HTML like so:

```
  <a-asset-item id="model-obj" src="http://localhost:8080/dashboard/portal/downloadObj/12b557b5-25d8-459c-b4ea-2bddce34c3af?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUz"></a-asset-item>
```

but I really need to build it dynamically with some help from Angular with something like this:

```
  <a-asset-item id="model-obj" [src]="srcUrl"></a-asset-item>
```

But every time I do that a-frame won't actually pick up the src attribute properly - probably because it's not getting the src URL at run time. I know I'm getting the right string put in there, and I've already tried this to no avail: [A-Frame not loading assets from Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754417/a-frame-not-loading-assets-from-angular)

Any ideas of how I can do this?

Comment: Running into similar issue. Tried `="{{my_id}}"` as well, and properties are not being set.

Comment: Yeah - same idea

Answer (score 2):

Working solution around Angular's data-binding delay:

```
<a-asset-item
  *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: trackItem"
  id="placeholder"
  src="placeholder.glb"
  [attr.id]="item?.id"
  [attr.src]="item?.uri">
</a-asset-item>
```

Issue is that data-binding doesn't happen immediately, and so A-Frame will error out because no `src` is provided at that moment in time.

Answer (score 0):

Asset management system doesn't work well in Angular, but there is the other way which is not officially recommended. Load your asset outside of aframe asset management system.
Docs: https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/primitives/a-gltf-model.html

See this answer in related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55477602/1345116

Answer (score 0):

You could wait to render the item until it has a src using *ngIf

But you’ll need to use a container because *ngFor and *ngIf cannot be used on the same element.

```
<a-container
`*ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: trackItem"`>
<a-asset-item
  *ngIf=“item && item.uri”
  id="placeholder"
  src="placeholder.glb"
  [attr.id]="item?.id"
  [attr.src]="item?.uri">
</a-asset-item>
<a-container>
```